# Sum 2 columns from multiple rows with same ID

Tags: oracle, sum

Currently, I have a table MY_TABLE like below:

```
ID  ACCT_TYPE  CREDIT_AMT  DEBIT_AMT 
--  ---------  ----------  ---------
1   CDT_01     4           (null)   
1   DBT_01     (null)      6
```

One ID can have multiple ACCT_TYPE like above, and each type has its own amount.

I want to just select the row which has ACCT_TYPE like 'CDT_%' but also the total_amount column which is the total of credit_amt and debit_amt column for the same ID.

My expected output like below:

```
ID  ACCT_TYPE  TOTAL_AMT
--  ---------  ---------
1   CDT_01     10
```

I tried with this select statement below but it's no use, I think it's because of different ACCT_TYPE:

```
Select ID, ACCT_TYPE, SUM(NVL(CREDIT_AMT, 0) + NVL(DEBIT_AMT, 0)) TOTAL_AMT 
FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ACCT_TYPE LIKE 'CDT_%' GROUP BY ID, ACCT_TYPE;
```

Here is the output of the select statement above:

```
ID  ACCT_TYPE  TOTAL_AMT  
--  ---------  ---------  
1   CDT_01     4
```

I just begin to learn some query so I don't know is it really possible to get my expected output.

Comment: If I assume an id has more than 2 account type other than `CDT%` and `DBT%` then you only need sum of these two but the output should show record with `CDT%` row ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Actually my ACCT_TYPE column will contain only DBT% and CDT%. I found those answer below helps :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like below:

```
with inputs (ID,  ACCT_TYPE,  CREDIT_AMT,  DEBIT_AMT) as
(
    select 1,   'CDT_01',     4,         null from dual union all
    select 1,   'DBT_01',     null,      6  from dual 
),
prep as
(
    select  t.*, sum(nvl(credit_amt,0)) over (partition by id) + sum(nvl(debit_amt,0)) over (partition by id) as sum_per_id
    from    inputs t
)
select  id, acct_type, sum_per_id 
from    prep
where   acct_type like 'CDT_%';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery might be one option; sample data (thank you, @Ranagal) in lines #1 - 5; query that does the job begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with inputs (ID,  ACCT_TYPE,  CREDIT_AMT,  DEBIT_AMT) as
  2  (
  3      select 1,   'CDT_01',     4,         null from dual union all
  4      select 1,   'DBT_01',     null,      6  from dual
  5  )
  6  select a.id,
  7         a.acct_type,
  8         (select sum(nvl(b.credit_amt, 0)) +
  9                 sum(nvl(b.debit_amt , 0))
 10          from inputs b
 11          where b.id = a.id
 12         ) total_amt
 13  from inputs a
 14  where acct_type like 'CDT%';

        ID ACCT_T  TOTAL_AMT
---------- ------ ----------
         1 CDT_01         10

SQL>
```